# Why does my string length subroutine give an infinity loop?

Tags: mips

I want my code to print the length of a string, but instead it seems to enter an infinity loop. I cannot understand where my error is.

```
.data 
STR_str:
.asciiz "Hello"
#################################
main: 

la  $a0, STR_str
jal string_length

add $a0, $v0, $zero
li  $v0, 1
syscall
############################################
string_length:

li $v0, 0 # initialize the count to zero
str_lenght_loop:
lb $t2, 0($a0) # load the next character into t2
loop_strlen: beqz $t2, exit # check for the null character
addi $a0, $a0, 1 # increment the string pointer
addi $v0, $v0, 1 # increment the count
j loop_strlen # return to the top of the loop
exit:  
jr $ra
```

Comment: Then it's time to start finding out why: make your string one character long. You should now be perfectly able to write out, with pen and paper, what happens at each of this rather low number of lines, and  you should be able to write out exactly why your code keeps running instead of halting.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation? I can't get it right.

Comment: literally get pen and paper, and start writing down what, at each line of execution, the content of your registers are (by looking at the instructions, _not_ the code comments), and determining the result of jump conditionals. There's about 10 lines you need to run through, and you "know" when it should stop, so: once you reach the point it should stop, your pen and paper trace should tell you why it doesn't.